# MapHttpRoute to the Swashbuckle Swagger UI to use custom handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, asp.net-web-api-routing, swashbuckle

I've got Swashbuckle going in my web api project. I want to get a custom handler invoked only when a user tries to hit the swagger ui page. I don't want to add the handler to the pipeline.

I thought something like this might work but it doesn't:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "SwaggerUI",
        routeTemplate: "docsite/{*assetPath}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: null,
        handler: new MyHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
```

I use route attributes everywhere else in the project so I map those attributes first.

My swagger config is using

```
.EnableSwaggerUi("docsite/{*assetPath}",c =>
```

hence the docsite route.

I don't want to add the handler to the pipeline because I don't want it to get called with every web api call. I'm using it to restrict access to the swagger UI.

Also I'm using OWIN to authenticate one particular api so I get this error when I try to call that api

```
The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'MyHandler' is not null.
Parameter name: handlers
```

Figured I can avoid the error by just making sure the handler only happens when I do a swagger ui route.

Who wants to help!

Comment: Why do you want to restrict access to the Swagger UI?

Comment: @HelderSepu Cuz my boss wants it that way :)  It's going to be publicly facing so we don't want everyone to be able to look at our api's, especially competitors.

Comment: I think I'm just going to branch Swashbuckle and change it to allow myself to add an inner message handler to the current message handler since the routing doesn't seem to work

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't really need to restrict access to the Swagger-UI, just change the swagger.json with an `IDocumentFilter` there you can wipe what you don't want others to see

Comment: @HelderSepu The Swagger page is a link on another document site which requires a login. We don't want them to go directly to the swagger ui without having to log in first. I didn't mention it before but the handler redirects them to the login page if they're not authenticated.